# Can JQuery Signature work on WinRT or Win8 App

Tags: jquery, winrt-xaml

-I have included the following in html file:

a) http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js 
b) JSignature.js from
https://github.com/brinley/jSignature/blob/master/libs/jSignature.min.js

-use WebView control to display this Html file.

Problem :

1) I can not draw my signature in the box on WinRT tablet(surface) using  WebView control to display the html file

2) Having above libraries (a and b) , Can this work on tablet such ipad, Android?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jSignature.js">   
 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#divSignature").jSignature({width:400, height:140, mousedown:function(){}});
        });

 </script>
```

Comment: So, the `WebView` is not a full-fledged browser. One thing it does not do well is gestures. What you'll likely have to do is monitor the gestures yourself outside of the `WebView` and then use `ScriptNotify` to to pass the pointer information in. It'd probably be easier to implement a custom control yourself. If you're using WinJS, you can probably reuse a lot of that code.

Comment: What about iPad and Android tablet, Will they face the same problem using the above same code? I dont have ipad.

Comment: That I don't know. You'll have to check on their WebView implementations. It's very possible not. WinRT is a very closed, sandboxed system. Opening a web page is downloading someone else's code and compiling it. There's a reason so many attacks are over the web. So, it's one of the most locked down features. WebView is not intended to be a full browser. It's an html sandbox.